# Datepicker date format not comparing with moment date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, momentjs

I have a datepicker on a registration page for selecting date of birth. The date picker works fine and if I capture its value (using javascript) it's value is correct (e.g. 4-12-1978)

In my function, which is using moment.js;

```
function checkBirthdate(dob) {
    // dob is coming from $('#validation-dateofbirth').val()   
    var allowed = false;
    var registerDate = moment().add(-18, "years").format("MM-DD-YYYY");

    if (dob.isValid()) {
         allowed = dob.isBefore(registerDate);
    }
        return allowed;
    }
```

when testing, dob.isValid is an error. Okay that became obvious, I was trying to compare a moment date with a non moment date. Therefore, I have to convert the datepicker's output to a moment date.

Adding

```
dob = moment(dob);
//I also tried using
dob = moment(dob, "MM-DD-YYYY");
```

to the function should've worked, since the passed in dob value was in the same format shown in many moment docs (well, I'm assuming the value from the datepicker is a string like "4-12-2016"), but it doesn't.

How can I convert the value coming from the datepicker (I'm using the bootstrap datepicker) to a moment date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker + Moment.js , can't seem to get format to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522587/bootstrap-3-datepicker-moment-js-cant-seem-to-get-format-to-work)

Comment: Which is the value of `dob`? Is it a moment object, a string or a js date?

Comment: @Mosh Feu..not if you actually read that post, which i did, there is nothing in that that is applicable here.

Comment: @VincenzoC...the passed in parameter, as shown in the posted code, is coming from the selector.val(), that is what I don't know, is that val coming as a string or something else. Probably isn't a string or my moment converting would work.

Comment: @dinotom what is the output of `console.log( $('#validation-dateofbirth').val() );`? `val()` usually returns the string value of the input. Since you are using bootstrap-datepicker you can use [`getDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#getdate) method to get picker value as js date. Moreover what is `4-12-1978`? The 4th of December or the 12th of April? Try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (e.g. a snippet or a fiddle).

Comment: @VincenzoC...your original comment got me to go and look at the datepickers format, which was in dd/mm/yyyy format. I changed that to match the moment format and now it is working by changing dob to a moment object using dob=moment(dob,"MM-DD-YYYY");

Comment: @dinotom so maybe the post is a little relevant due it talks about the format..

Comment: @Mosh Feu...That post is about "Displaying" a date in a specific format. My question was how to create a proper moment object which has nothing to do with displaying the date. The fact that moment was not converting the selector val() to the proper moment format, IF it wasn't in that format already, was the issue, but certainly in no way solved by reading that post.